# multi text box i.e. textarea export to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to do export to excel functionality using javascript. My array looks this way.The column Remarks is a multi text box, So when I export the next line is appending in a new cell, instead of splitting the same call. Can someoe help me out? 
[image]